# Re-use computed structures for moves & score calculation

Tags: optaplanner

When computing score and in my MoveIteratorFactories I need to compute the same data structures from a given solution.

What's the best way to compute those data structures only once for any given solution?

Thanks,

Antoine

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're saying/asking, but do you know about [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)?

Comment: Well basically I have to construct some indexes from the solution, but I want to only compute them once. If I memoize the computations and  store them on the solution instance, I need to know when to invalidate them (when the working solution has changed). I hope that's a bit more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **shadow variables (PlanningVariableListener)** you can store those computer structures on your domain model, in which case they are available for your custom move factories too.

Internally, OptaPlanner (as of 6.2) uses a Supply and Demand system to have such calculated structures available without 1) requiring them to be on the domain model (through an externalized Supply) and 2) without doing the calculations more than once (because multiple Demands get the same Supply) and 3) only doing the calculations if they are needed (no Demand means no Externalized Supply). But that's internal API, so you shouldn't use that...